# How to check if a kernel does local or global scheduling for threads

Tags: c, multithreading, process, linux-kernel, scheduler

Which part of the code in `kernel/sched/core.c` do I see to tell which type of scheduling the kernel is using for scheduling the threads. Or am I looking in the right place at all? A multiple process can have multiple threads and how are these individual threads scheduled? On a process basis (local) or by a thread pool (global)

**EDIT:**

I am currently recording the `context_switch` that occurs in the `core.c` file to see how processes are switched. But when I try to analyse this data its getting too complicated. Could anyone suggest an easier method?

I found this at http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/include/linux/sched.h#L36

```
  /*
   * Scheduling policies
  */
  #define SCHED_NORMAL            0
  #define SCHED_FIFO              1
  #define SCHED_RR                2
  #define SCHED_BATCH             3
  /* SCHED_ISO: reserved but not implemented yet */
  #define SCHED_IDLE              5
```

But I donot see it used anywhere in a manner I can understand.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but are you sure *"which type of scheduling the kernel is using"* is a sensible question?  My understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the scheduler is a fixed algorithm [whose code you can pretty much read through](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/sched.c), and its state is what you've got to work with.  I gathered these constants were things you could query on a per-process basis via [`sched_getscheduler()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html), not on a "per-kernel" basis.

Comment: @HostileFork I want to know it for threads. Sorry for the ambigious question. I have edited the question

Comment: Did you look at the link to [kernel/sched.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/sched.c) from my comment above?  Also, [this PDF from 2005](http://joshaas.net/linux/linux_cpu_scheduler.pdf) is old but accessible...and probably a lot of it still applies.

Comment: @HostileFork I did look at that file. But I am getting confused and I need some hints and pointers on where is what.

Comment: Well, one doesn't jump into an OS kernel and just magically know what's what!  You can do keyword searches on "thread" and try and trace your way through, or visit Amazon/TheLibrary for something more up-to-date like [*Linux Kernel Development*](http://blog.rlove.org/2010/07/linux-kernel-development-third-edition.html).  (I'd personally start with the PDF because it's free and instantly available, despite being a bit old.)  Browsing questions tagged with [both linux and scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux+scheduler) could lead to hints, also.

Comment: This article might also be helpful: http://lse.sourceforge.net/scheduling/mq1.html